# Writing a BATCH File IF EXIST not working

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch file to install some software, but first I need to know if the system is 32 bit or 64 bit, and then goto the appropriate install. My code so far looks like this:

```
IF EXIST C:\Program File(x86) (
GOTO 64bit_install 
) ELSE (
GOTO 32bit_install )
```

No matter what system I try to install on, it always goes to the 64 bit install. I've tested the script on both a 32 bit VM and 64 bit VM. When I swap the GOTO statements, it just goes to the first GOTO XXbit_install. It's ignoring the ELSE statement. Please help!

Comment: You need to enclose file names or paths with spaces in double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose file names and paths that have spaces with double quotes.  You also spelled the directory name incorrectly.

```
IF EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)" (
GOTO 64bit_install 
) ELSE (
GOTO 32bit_install )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new to Batch files, and the syntax escapes me.

Comment: @flyingtam You might want to mark the above as an answer (hit the checkbox under the vote buttons) to close the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I did find another answer that is working as well. I was searching for IF EXIST, when I should have been looking for checking OS with BATCH or something. Here is the solution that worked:

```
IF EXIST "%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%" (GOTO 64bit_Install) ELSE (GOTO 32bit_Install)
```